# S3 Replication Cross Region using Terraform giving error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, storage, terraform-provider-aws

I want to replicate s3 buckets across regions of aws with terraform.

This is my code in my s3.tf:

```
# Bucket

module "s3_replica" {
  source = "git@github.com:xxx"

  providers = {
    aws     = "aws.us-west-2"
  }

  name                  = "s3_replica"
  logging_bucket_prefix = "s3_replica"
  versioning            = var.versioning
  bucket_logging        = var.bucket_logging
  logging_bucket_name   = var.logging_bucket_name

  kms_key_id    = aws_kms_key.s3-replica-key.key_id
  sse_algorithm = var.sse_algorithm
  tags          = var.bucket_tags
  environment   = var.environment
}

module "s3" {
  source                = "git@github.com:xxxx"
  name                  = "s3"
  logging_bucket_prefix = "s3"
  versioning            = var.versioning
  bucket_logging        = var.bucket_logging
  logging_bucket_name   = var.logging_bucket_name

  kms_key_id    = aws_kms_key.s3.key_id
  sse_algorithm = var.sse_algorithm
  tags          = var.bucket_tags
  environment   = var.environment

replication_configuration {
  role = aws_iam_role.replication_role.arn
  
  rules {
    status = "Enabled"
    
    destination {
      bucket = aws_s3_bucket.module.s3_replica.bucket_arn
      storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
      replicate_kms_key_id = aws_kms_key.s3-replica-key.key_id
    }
    
    source_selection_criteria {
      sse_kms_encrypted_objects {
        enabled = true
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

and this is my part of my module:

```
  dynamic "replication_configuration" {
    for_each = length(keys(var.replication_configuration)) == 0 ? [] : [var.replication_configuration]

    content {
      role = replication_configuration.value.role

      dynamic "rules" {
        for_each = replication_configuration.value.rules

        content {
          id       = lookup(rules.value, "id", null)
          priority = lookup(rules.value, "priority", null)
          prefix   = lookup(rules.value, "prefix", null)
          status   = rules.value.status

          dynamic "destination" {
            for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "destination", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "destination", {})]

            content {
              bucket             = destination.value.bucket
              storage_class      = lookup(destination.value, "storage_class", null)
              replica_kms_key_id = lookup(destination.value, "replica_kms_key_id", null)
              account_id         = lookup(destination.value, "account_id", null)
            }
          }

          dynamic "source_selection_criteria" {
            for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "source_selection_criteria", {})]

            content {

              dynamic "sse_kms_encrypted_objects" {
                for_each = length(keys(lookup(source_selection_criteria.value, "sse_kms_encrypted_objects", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(source_selection_criteria.value, "sse_kms_encrypted_objects", {})]

                content {

                  enabled = sse_kms_encrypted_objects.value.enabled
                }
              }
            }
          }

          dynamic "filter" {
            for_each = length(keys(lookup(rules.value, "filter", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(rules.value, "filter", {})]

            content {
              prefix = lookup(filter.value, "prefix", null)
              tags   = lookup(filter.value, "tags", null)
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }

resource "aws_iam_role" "replication" {
  name = "s3-bucket-replication"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "replication" {
  name = "s3-bucket-replication"

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "module.s3.bucket_arn"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "module.s3.bucket_arn"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:ReplicateObject",
        "s3:ReplicateDelete"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "module.s3.bucket_arn"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "replication" {
  name       = "s3-bucket-replication"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.replication.name]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.replication.arn
}
}
```

When I run terraform init.. it is successful.
However, when I run terraform plan it gives me this error:

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on s3.tf line 102, in module "s3":
 102: replication_configuration {

Blocks of type "replication_configuration" are not expected here.
```

Why am I getting this error? I do have the replication_confirguration right?

- Is there a configuration problem or a syntax problem?

I tried adding "=" in front of the configurations.. and now I get the error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on s3.tf line 102, in module "s3":
 102: replication_configuration = {

An argument named "replication_configuration" is not expected here.
```

Comment: What is the full resource using dynamic `replication_configuration`?

Comment: @Marcin it is the "module "s3""

Comment: You can't pass block into modules. You also have `dynamic "replication_configuration"`? Where is it from? Can you provide full defintion of a resource using `dynamic "replication_configuration"`?

Comment: @Marcin I took it from here https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/examples/s3-replication/main.tf ..  and https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-s3-bucket/blob/master/main.tf

Comment: The link is correct. They use `replication_configuration = {`, but you have `replication_configuration {`.

Comment: @Marcin i tried doing that too... se question I updated

Comment: The `replication_configuration` is valid in module `terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws`. But you are using `git@github.com:xxxx` module? is it same as `terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws`? Probably not, because you get the error about not supported  `replication_configuration`.